# How can I save an array that I created very timeconsumigly before. So I can reuse it without running the line of code again?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, pickle, camelot-php-tools

This lines of code extracts all tables from page 667-795 from a pdf and saves them into an array full of tables.

```
tablesSys = cam.read_pdf("840Dsl_sysvar_lists_man_0122_de-DE_wichtig.pdf",
                         pages = "667-795", 
                         process_threads = 100000, 
                         line_scale = 100, 
                         strip_text ='.\n'
                        ) 

tablesSys = np.array(tablesSys)
```

The array looks like this.

[image]

Later I have to use this array multiple times.

Now I work with jupyter lab and whenever my kernel gets offline or I start working again after hours or when I restart the kernel etc. I have to call up this line of code to get my tablesSys. Which takes more then 11 minutes to load.

Since the pdf doesn't change at all, I think that I could find a way to only load the code once and save the array somehow. So in the furture I can use the array without loading the code.

Hope to find a solution :)))

Comment: Try using the pickle format to save a pickle file to the file system https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pickle format to save a pickle file to the file system https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

See a high-level example here, I did not run this code but it should give you an idea.

```py
import pickle

import numpy as np

# calculate the huge data slice
heavy_numpy_array = np.zeros((1000,2)) # some data

# decide where to store the data in the file-system
my_filename = 'path/to/my_file.xyz'
my_file = open(my_filename, 'wb')

# save to file
pickle.dump(heavy_numpy_array, my_file)
my_file.close()

# load the data from file
my_file_v2 = open(my_filename, 'wb')
my_long_numpy_array = pickle.load(my_file_v2)
my_file_v2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Was playing around...**

```
import numpy as np


class Cam:
    def read_pdf(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.random.rand(3, 2)


cam = Cam()

tablesSys = cam.read_pdf(
    "840Dsl_sysvar_lists_man_0122_de-DE_wichtig.pdf",
    pages="667-795",
    process_threads=100000,
    line_scale=100,
    strip_text=".\n",
)


with open("data.npy", "wb") as f:
    np.save(f, tablesSys)

with open("data.npy", "rb") as f:
    tablesSys = np.load(f)
print(tablesSys)
```